# I don't know how to get id of records while deleting record using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#submit").click(function (){

    var name =$("#name").val();
    var mobile =$("#mobile").val();
    var email =$("#email").val();

    $.get('new.php',{name : name, mobile: mobile, email: email},function (data){
    $("#res").html(data);
    });

        $("#name").val("");
        $("#mobile").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
        $("#res").hide(10000);
    });//submit.click end here!!!!!!!


    $("#view").click(function(){
        var view='view';
        $.post('new.php',{view: view},function(data){
        $("#viewdata").html(data);      

        });

        $("#viewdata").toggle("slow");

    });//to display data in table!!!!!!!

    $("#add").click(function(){
    $("#addnew").toggle("slow");

    });//toggel button for record table!!!!!


$("body").on('click','',function(){     

    var iddata =this.id.split('-');
    var id = iddata[1];

    alert(id);  

    });


</script>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['view']))
{
$query="select * from userdetail";
$res=mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border=1> 
<tr><th>name</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th></tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".$row[4]."</td>";
    echo "<td><div class='del' id='id-".$row[0]."';>Delete</div></td>"; 
    echo "<td><a href='#'>Update</a></td>"; 

    }
    echo"</table>";
}
```

```
<body>

<div  id="addnew" style="width:500px; float:left;">

<div style="width:200px; float:left;">
<form name="frm" id="frm">
<input type="text" id="name"></br>
<input type="text" id="mobile"></br>
<input type="text" id="email"></br>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/></br>
</form>
</div>

<div id="res" style="width:300px; float:left;">

</div>

</div>

<button id="add">Add New</button>
<button id="view">View</button>

<div id="viewdata">
<table border=1> 
<tr>
<th>name</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th>
</tr>
</div>

</body>
```

I'm new in jquery and trying to learn crud function with jquery and php. I'm working on a code where I can add data through jquery as well as I can  retrieve it from database, now I have placed a delete field to delete record from that table but I'm stuck here because I don't know how to get id from that table so I can use it to delete that record from table.  I have tried .on and delegate in jquery to get that id but still not getting the result what I want, so please help me to solve this error.

Comment: If you are learning, learn about mysqli_* or PDO. NOT MySQL_* (The PHP Extension)

Comment: If you wrote the code you are showing then you should at least be able to start coding the delete functionality. So I guess you didnt write it. **So you want us to write it for you** SO **is no a free coding service** You write it, if you have problems we are more than willing to help, **but we dont write it for you**

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, they wrote it anyway.

Comment: @AlanMachado Someone normally does. The hunger for reputation takes over. So now we have another PHP/Javascript developer out there with no idea what they are doing. So more awful code for one of us to fix when the client wants mods/upgrades

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i have written that whole code and i'm searching for the  solution from today morning  to yet. and sir i have read more than 20 question and there solution but still did not get the result what i want and i'm not asking you to write down whole code i m just asking you that how can i get the id of record while i'm fetching that data from database using j query i hope you understand and i can delete that record using php if i'm not fetching though jquery. btw thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing id inside while loop, I can fetch it using bellow code
in html page.

**I can use**

```
$<'#viewdata'>.on('click','.del',function(){
  alert(this.id);
})
```

It will popup the result like `id-31` or `id-1` (whatever is selected).

Now you can use that id to delete the record.
`.del` is a class where id is stored in php file

**e.g**

```
< class='del' id=$row['id']>delete
```

Answer (score 1):

So your html output is going to be something like this for your delete cell

```
    <td>
        <div class='del' id='id-1'>Delete</div>
    </td>
```

Within JQuery you can do this:

```
$('.del').on('click',function() {alert(this.id)});
```

***Result:*** `id-1`

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/54nptrkd/

Comment: yes you are right its gives above output like  <div class='del' id='id-1'>Delete</div> now i will just try as you say ind get back to you btw thank you so much!!!

Comment: as you say its working on http://jsfiddle.net/54nptrkd/ but still not working on my code. is it possible to delete record from that table? i mean how it is work? becouse there is a number of rows so how can i get correct id??

Comment: Are you just trying to remove that table from the dom? Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/54nptrkd/1/

Comment: let me explain you whole thing. i have two page the first one is html where i'm displaying records with the help of jquery and another one which is php file. now i'm fetching the records from data base using jquery and displaying that records. now there is a link to delete that each of individual row of the record e.g if i click on row 1 then it will delete the row 1 records from the database. so whole record is fetched though while loop and link is also placed in that loop so how the problem is i'm not able to get the id of row using jquery or i mean how can i get it. thank you

Comment: are you trying to hit a delete.php with the id, similiar to how you hit add.php with the new data?

Comment: Do you have a delete.php?

Comment: nope i dont have it separate file. delete code is also written in the same php file e.g if(isset($_GET['id'])){//code to delete record of that  id }

Comment: Do an $.ajax call to the file that contains your delete code and pass the id in the parameters (data attribute).  -documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ok i'm trying and can you refer me some stuff or link to learn delete and update using jquery and php

Answer (score 0):

"ok i'm trying and can you refer me some stuff or link to learn delete and update using jquery and php"

Your SQL statement will be something along the lines of

```
Delete from *TABLE* where id = ?
```

You most likely will have a Delete.php file that you can run your sql queries the same as you did in your New.php. Delete.php will either listen to a $_POST or $_GET variable

Your JQuery will have an ajax call like this if you are using $_POST in your php

```
$.ajax('Delete.php?id='+id,{
  success: function() {
   alert('it worked!')
  }
});
```

or like this if you are using $_GET in your php

```
$.ajax('Delete.php', {
  id: id,
  success: function() {
   alert('it worked!')
  }
});
```

id will be defined in your JS like I mentioned before

```
$('.del').on('click',function() {
  alert(this.id)
  var id = this.id;
  //$.ajax call goes here
});
```

Comment: ok now im creating one separated delete.php file and try as you say btw thanks seth McClaine for your valuable help

Comment: hi seth  i have tried as you explained but there is a one problem in this code. $('.del ').on('click',function) if not working i mean when i see the source code of the table it is display the id value as id='id-1', 2 , and so on but when i click on that delete field its do nothing.

Comment: Can you put what you have in jsfiddle?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#view").click(function(){
  var view='view';
  $.post('deletedata.php',{view: view},function(data){
  $("#viewdata").html(data);  
   
  });
  $("#viewdata").toggle("slow");
  //toggel button for record table!!!!!

 });
 
$('.del').on('click',function() {
  alert(this.id)
  var id = this.id;
  //$.ajax call goes here

$.ajax('deletedata.php', {
  id: id,
  success: function(data) {
   alert(data)
  }
});
});


});
</script>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['view']))
{
$query="select * from userdetail";
$res=mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border=1> 

<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".$row[4]."</td>";
 echo "<td><div class='del' id='id-".$row[0]."'>Delete</a></td>"; 
 }
 echo"</table>";
}

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
 
$uid=$_POST['id'];
$query="delete from userdetail where uid=".$uid;
$res=mysql_query($query);
if($res)
{ echo "Record deleted!!";  }

else {echo "Can not able to delete"; } 
}

Comment: hey seth thank you for your help finnaly today i find out the solution of my problem. i have place id at <div class='del' id='$row[id]'>delete</div> in php file and i'm able to select that id using $('#viewdata').on ('click','.del',function(){ alert(this.id);}); and its working. thank you dear